# Bootstrap: Allow an image to extend on top of the DIV?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue getting an image to appear to "overflow" the DIV it is residing in.

A simple example:

```
 <div class="container callout-blue">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6"> Some content</div>
         <div class="col-md-6"> 
             <img src="myimage.png" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs center" />
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

With the desired effect of having the container-div with a blue background, but have the image  appear to spill over the top of the div. Say the blue-background is 200px high, and the image is 300px high, having the top 100px of the image appear above the callout div.

Answer (score 0):

change your HTML like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 overbox"> <img src="myimage.png" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs center" /></div>
```

and now apply your CSS like this:

```
.overbox{position:relative;}
.overbox img{position:absolute; left:0; top:-100px;}
```